# mysql counting duplicates - grouping by two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table, "Clicks", as so. It generates a new row every time a user clicks an item:

```
item    user_id
1511     787
1511     432 
1511     522             
1511     432
```

I need a count of the duplicate values in the user_id column grouped by the item number (there are millions of them). So in this case it would be 1. If user 432 clicked on the item 3 times, it would still be 1. But if user 787 clicked on it twice and user 432 clicked on it 585,895 times, then it'd be 2.

I know how to count row items and group, but not when it comes to grouping both columns and returning the count of the dupes.

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

(desired result - based on the table I already presented)

```
SELECT c.item, count(? - still unsure on query) AS multi_clickers FROM clicks c

item    multi_clickers
1511      1
1512      ? 
1513      ?          
1514      ?
```

Comment: can you show your wished results ?

Comment: Is it necessary to eliminate rows where an item was clicked by only one user, or only by one user one time? Or would you also include that?

Comment: sorry, please see the edit I made above, hopefully it's more clear

Comment: @spencer7593 I want to eliminate any row that doesn't repeat, basically. So if 10 different users click on an item, the count is 0. If 10 different users click on an item, but 2 of those 10 click more than once, it will be 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select item, count(userid) as multi_clickers
from
  (select item, userid, count(userid) as total_clicks_for_user
   from clicks 
   group by item, userid
   having total_clicks_for_user > 1) a
group by item
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2170c/6